# Background colour of LaTeX template

Tags: color

How to change the background colour of LaTeX file template? Not the output file.

I have a white background and white font. So I am not able to see the text I am typing.

Comment: You appear to be talking about the setup of the editor you are using, but you have not said what editor that is. LaTeX itself just takes a text file with a document, you can use any editor to create that file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There's no easy way: in the help window of TeXShop, look for "How do I configure TeXShop" and choose the item "Hidden Preference Items”.